# EF6 generates weird foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am having a little problem using EF 6. These are my models (well, I am omitting the non-relevant properties):

```cs
[Table("Departments")]
public class Department
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<Staff> Staff { get; set; }

    public Staff HOD { get; set; }
}

[Table("Staff")]
public class Staff
{
    [Key]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

This is the migration that EF6 is generating (well, just the create methods):

```cs
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Staff",
    c => new
        {
            EmployeeId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            Name = c.String(),
            Department_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
            Department_Id1 = c.String(maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.EmployeeId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.Department_Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.Department_Id1)
    .Index(t => t.Department_Id)      //what's this?
    .Index(t => t.Department_Id1);    //what's this?

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Departments",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            Name = c.String(),
            Description = c.String(),
            HOD_EmployeeId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Staff", t => t.HOD_EmployeeId)
    .Index(t => t.HOD_EmployeeId);
```

Take a look at the foreign keys generated. Something seems to be amiss. How do I correct this?

Comment: do you have any code in the `OnModelCreating` method override for your DB context? The naming conventions generated by the migration don't look very standard which is leading me to assume you've got some custom code overriding the model builder somewhere.

Comment: Just `RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention`

Comment: Add a nullable HODId column to Department and configure that as the FK for HOD.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to use Fluent API to make this relationship work:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
    .HasRequired<Department>(staff => staff.Department)
    .WithMany(department => department.Staff)
    .HasForeignKey<string>(staff => staff.DepartmentId);
```

Changes to the models:

```cs
public Department Department { get; set; }
```

changed to

```cs
public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

and

```cs
public IList<Staff> Staff { get; set; }

public Staff HOD { get; set; }
```

changed to

```cs
public virtual IList<Staff> Staff { get; set; }

public Staff HOD { get; set; }
```

Comment: any special reason for DVing, DVer?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would be better if the answer contained the corrected model/configuration, instead of just the changes.

Comment: Well, the Model is literally the same! Why would it be any different? If it were, I would surely have added it in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add some relations

```
[Table("Departments")]
public class Department
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Staff> Staff { get; set; }

     public  int HodId {get set;}

     [ForeignKey("HodId")]
    public Staff Hod { get; set; }
}

[Table("Staff")]
public class Staff
{
    [Key]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It still adds 2 Foreign keys on the Staff table, when there should only be one

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Fluent API?